# Remove punctuation from references to task counter

Tags: cross-referencing, tasks

I'm using the *tasks* environment to spread a list across two columns. But the *\ref* command appears to carry punctuation with it differently than it does in the *enumerate* environment. I want to produce the following:

[image: Image of what I want to produce]

The following code puts a "2." in the paragraph instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
Task \ref{keytask} is more important.
\begin{tasks}[counter-format={tsk[1].},label-format=\bfseries](2)
    \task First task
    \task\label{keytask} Second task
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of first code example]

And this variation puts no "2" into the paragraph at all:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}
\newcounter{customcounter}
\newcommand{\customlabel}{
    \refstepcounter{customcounter}
    \llap{\bfseries\thecustomcounter.}}
\renewcommand{\thecustomcounter}{\arabic{customcounter}}
\settasks{label=\customlabel,label-align=right}

\begin{document}
Task \ref{keytask} is more important.
\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task First task
    \task\label{keytask} Second task
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of second code example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an up to date version of `tasks` you can separate the numbering form the formatting. This makes it very easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}[2020-01-11]% use version 1.1a or later
\newcommand*\tasklabelfmt[1]{\textbf{#1.}}

\settasks{
  label = \arabic* ,
  label-format = \tasklabelfmt
}

\begin{document}

Task~\ref{keytask} is more important.
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task First task
  \task\label{keytask} Second task
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is a crazy sounding X-mas proposal that makes use of the fact that in LaTeX definitions are local.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}
\newcommand{\mydot}{}
\begin{document}
Task \ref{keytask} is more important.
\begin{tasks}[counter-format={tsk[1]\mydot},label-format=\bfseries\renewcommand{\mydot}{.}](2)
    \task First task
    \task\label{keytask} Second task
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is such a clever idea!

Comment: Thanks! I want to avoid including these options in every _tasks_ environment in my document. I can't get it to work using the _\settasks_ part, but I used your trick to define a new environment: `\NewTasks[counter-format={tsk[1]\mydot},label-format=\bfseries\renewcommand{\mydot}{.}]{mytasks}[\mytask]`

Comment: This worked at the time and was the accepted answer, but newer versions of the tasks environment have both made an easier solution possible and broken this solution.